# For statement in jenkinsfile but using the variable for different stages

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a list variable that i want to cycle over and i am able to do that but i can't seem to call it in my bat statement. Any idea how?

```
def birds = ["Parrot", "Cockatiel", "Pigeon"]

pipeline 
{


    agent any
    stages 
    {

        stage('Build Job1') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                script 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < birds.size(); ++i) 
                    {
                        echo "Testing the ${birds[i]} browse"
                        bat 'echo ${birds[i]}'

                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        stage ('Hello')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < birds.size(); ++i) 
                    {
                        echo "Testing the ${birds[i]} browser"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the batch statements like below. Simply surround with double quotes.

```
bat "echo ${birds[i]}"
```